# Large vertical brackets for limits of definite integrals.

Tags: support, mathjax

How do I make a large vertical bracket for definite integrals like this one? $|_0^t$

Is there a link to a page containing tags for all symbols? I have looked and my page search never lists one although I am certain one exists because I have seen it before.

Comment: [Related discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11795/11619).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option, though it doesn't automatically change its size, is to use `\bigl|`.  You can manually change the size by using `\bigl|, \Bigl|, \biggl|, \Biggl|`, as in
$$\bigl|, \Bigl|, \biggl|, \Biggl|$$
Replacing `l` by `r` allows you to make right-justified symbols (this only changes the spacing in relation to the objects around it), and change `|` to any of `(,),],[,\{,\}` allows you to do the same with those symbols as well.

Comment: You can also use `\bigr` and so on, which is spaced to fit just to the right of something.  Here's `\biggl` and `\biggr`: $$\frac{x^2-1}{x}  \biggl|_1^2\qquad\frac{x^2-1}{x}  \biggr|_1^2$$ Looks like no difference in this case.

Comment: Yes, I pointed out that possibility in my answer, but it's probably best to give an example, as you did.  The difference is extremely minute, however (looks to me like a pixel or two).

Answer (score 7):

You want the code  `\left. {}\right|_{}^{}`. The dot after `\left` makes the left delimiter not appear. In general `\left \right` gives self adjusting delimiters. For example, `\left. \frac{x^2-1}{x}  \right|_1^2` gives $$\left. \frac{x^2-1}{x}  \right|_1^2$$

Comment: I like your answer but I also need the lookup page which contains tags for all symbols in Tex. Do you have it?

Comment: @JulesManson In the search page, input "TeX tutorial."

Comment: Thank you Pedro. My question was satisfactorily answered and I closed the post with a green checkmark.

Comment: The green checkmark is not "closing the post" but "accepting the answer".  That was the proper thing to do if it answered your question.